# Regex for != and = in with same pattern

Tags: regex

I have this:

```
a!=b

b=b
```

I would like one pattern for both cases.
I set

```
(.\*)(!=|=)(.\*)
```

But `=` is taken instead of the `!=` even if I put it first..
so I get group1 = a! and group2 = b

Any simple solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
^\w!?=\w$
```

`^`: Start string.

`$`: End string.

`\w`: Alphabet or numeric character (1 times).

`!?`: Character `!` zero or 1 times.

`=`: Character `=`.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `?` after the first asterisk to make it lazy / non-greedy :

```
(.*?)(!=|=)(.*)
```

Comment: Heh, turns out you should have, I was using the opposite term. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use don't match operator `^`:

```
([^!=]+)(!?=)([^!=]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same structure of your pattern, then you have to use a non greedy operator

```
(.*?)(!=|=)(.*)
   ^--- Here
```

However, you can still shorten your pattern and use this:

```
(.*?)(!?=)(.*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/SzmtfU/1)**

Additionally, if you want to match at least one operand at the operator sides you could use:

```
(.+?)(!?=)(.+)
```

[image]